# Java process exceeds allocated ram and crashes VPS

Tags: java

I have a vps running ubuntu `Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS` with Java version `1.7.0_65`.  I am running a minecraft server (I have attempted to use different jars for the server).  I execute that jar using the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh  
java -jar -Xmx1G -Xms1G glowstone.jar
```

The vps has 2G of ram and is also running a teamspeak server.  After a couple minutes the entire VPS crashes.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What makes you think it crashes? Could it be that the VPS server killed your processes because you used more ressources than you were allowed? Where is the VPS hosted and what are the conditions to use it? Did you speak with your VPS provider?

Comment: I am using linode which monitors memory and I see the memory hit max, and then the server crashes.  It has 2G ram and is hosted in newark I believe, I feel like running a minecraft server with half of the VPS's ram should not be a problem.  http://gyazo.com/1717fd4746495b1a46e5c2cef76df614 picture of analytics

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed a bug in some commercial Java based applications, where the application is well behaved in 32bit Java but requires an extra (and mostly unnecessary) 1.25GB just to get started on 64bit Java. So what takes 256MB in 32bit Java takes 1.5GB on a 64bit runtime.

I suspect that Java is reporting what it thinks the application is using, but not its own runtime overhead, particularly in the case where this bug is invoked.

You could try running the app on a 32 bit runtime, or going back to the vendor's tech support (may cost $$) and asking what's up.

Ultimately, if you succeed in limiting total memory footprint, you just force the app to crash sooner, and you are still left with a problem.

Comment: How would I run it in 32 bit?